# Getting price depending on day of the week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

If I have a table that stores the price for different days of the week, how would I use the appropriate column depending on the current day?

table structure:

```
room_id | mon   | tue   | wed   | thu   | fri   | sat   | sun
1       | 50.00 | 40.00 | 50.00 | 55.00 | 60.00 | 60.00 | 40.00
```

If I needed the price for today (01 feb 2013 - friday) for `room_id#1`, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `SELECT fri FROM table WHERE room_id=1` ?

Comment: Could you not set the table up with a day column and seven rows instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you get the day in PHP. Either today, or a date selected in a form.

```
$date = date(); // this grabs today, but you can enter any date you want
$day = date('D', $date); // this gets Mon / Tue / ...
$day = strtolower($day);

$query = "SELECT `{$day}` as price FROM `table` WHERE room_id = 1";
```

This should select only the correct price.

And here is similar code for the new(ish) [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class

```
$date = new DateTime();
$day = strtolower($date->format('D'));
```

**References:**

- http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php

Comment: +1: I think its not require strtotime($date) just $day = strtolower(date('D'));

Answer (score 4):

here a pure sql version.

```
SELECT  room_ID,
        CASE DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
            WHEN 1 THEN sun
            WHEN 2 THEN mon
            WHEN 3 THEN tue
            WHEN 4 THEN wed
            WHEN 5 THEN thu
            WHEN 6 THEN fri
            WHEN 7 THEN sat
        END price
FROM    tableName
// WHERE ....
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f51/1)
- [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

Another is by using `PreparedStatement` which you can wrap inside a stored procedure,

```
SET @dayName = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%a');
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT room_ID, `', @dayName, '` FROM tableName');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f51/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
$weekDays = array('sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat');
$day = $weekDays[date('w')];
mysql_query("SELECT ".$day." FROM table WHERE room_id = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like

```
$day = date('D',time());
$day = strtolower($day);
```

and then 
SELECT {$day} FROM table WHERE room_id = '1'

Answer (score 0):

You will save yourself grief over the long haul by restructuring your data - have a Day column (which could be enum('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun') for easy use and reading) which holds which day of the week your price applies and the query becomes (for Friday for example):

```
select price where room_id = 1 and day = 'Fri';
```

This makes your first query easy, but since you'll probably be doing reporting and other stuff later, it will make all subsequent queries easy too.

For a shortcut, if you make the enum('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat') to conform to the ODBC standard, you could then use:

```
select price where room_id = 1 and day = dayofweek(now());
```

(because the value of the first value of an enum is 1, second is 2, etc.)